# Memory Database with Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Usually sqlite allows to open a ":memory:" database. Is this supported in some way by Codename One?

The following example does not work in the simulator apparently because it tries to locate a file in the file system.

```
        Database db = Database.openOrCreate(":memory:");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time. If it just constitutes passing the value to the native layer we can probably implement a special case for that. So feel free to file an RFE.

FYI you can override our SQL implementation thanks to the new work we did here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/spatial-pluggable-sqlite.html